# Is Google Workbox v3.0.0-beta.0 available to install via npm?

Tags: workbox

I can see a couple of 3.0.0-alpha.1 under NPM
(I'm new to npm)

I think I used workbox-cli 2.1.2 before.

Answer (score 1):

OK, found this at 2nd attempt

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-cli
npm install workbox-cli@beta --global